# How to create numbered sub-lists in Mail application?

Tags: macos, mail.app, formatting

Is it possible to create nested numbered lists in MacOS's Mail client? —e.g.:

```
1. Foo
    1.1. Foo is cool
    1.2. Foo is great
2. Bar
    2.1. Bar is not so cool
    2.2. Bar is not so great
```

I've been trying but all attempts so far have failed. This is very basic stuff. There must be a way.

I'm using MacOS Sierra (10.12.6) and Mail version 10.3 (3273).

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to *say* 1.1, 1.2 etc? If you just tab it creates sub-lists, but it doesn't inherit the header number - e.g. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcHd2.png

Comment: I know, but if you're using nested lists to structure ideas, then the adequate number goes a long way to convey how `x.y` is further detail on `x`. Especially if the email eventually looses formatting or if the email thread gets too long and hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

In the Mail app go to the Format menu and click on lists and then on 'insert numbered list'. Go to your mail and enter text for the 1st item in the list. Now go back to the Format menu item and click on lists again and this time click on 'Increase List Level'. This will create sublists. See image below.

[image]

To go back to 1st level use Format/Lists/decrease list level.  You can create as many sublevels as you desire.

Comment: You can get the same result by typing Tab and Shift-Tab to increase/decrease. It doesn't create the number stile the OP asks for though.

Comment: sure it does. unless i'm confused about create. in a blank mail message i hit create numbered list and it creates a numbered list?  what am i missing?

Comment: Look at the example in the question. The OP wants the sublist to be numbered 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc

Comment: oh, ok. sorry. i thought he included that as an example of what he wanted.  Not neccessarily the only thing he wanted.